# Mercurial: fix a repository with several heads

Tags: mercurial

My repository has only two branches: default and stable. I made a mess in the stable branch but I have no clue on how to fix it.

[image: Current Repository]

The default branch is for new feature

```
92 is the revision created by the maven-release-plugin.
93 commit on stable
94 merge stable into default
95 to 98 commit on default
99 merge default into stable
100 to 103 commit on stable
104 try to fix the mess with a hg merge -r 98
```

For `default` I want the head to be `98`. For stable I want to go back to a single head including the commit `94` to `98`.

Comment: Looks like the only thing you need to do is to close the rev. 93 branch (or strip it), and merge 103 and 104 - everything else seems fine, doesn't it?

Comment: Or rebase 93 and 100...103 on to 104, as they are all phase 'draft'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Default`'s head should be 98; is it not? Run `hg heads default` to get the list of changesets that are heads on the `default` branch. From your graph, this is 98 and only 98.

For stable, it sounds like you want to `hg merge` commits 103 and 104. To do that, update to one of them (`hg update 103`), then merge the other one in (`hg merge 104`).

You'll still have to take care of commit 93. Did you want to have it in `stable` also? Or do you want to not have its effects? If you want to have it in `stable`, just merge it in also.

If you don't want its effects in `stable` at all, what you need to do will differ depending that's happened to it. Is it just on your local computer, or have you already pushed it upstream? If it's just on your local computer, running `hg strip 93` will remove it from your repository, and it won't get pushed remotely. To do this, you'll have to enable the [mq extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension).

If you have pushed 93 upstream, you can't strip it. What you can do, however, is make a commit that undoes the effects of 93 by updating to changeset 93, then running `hg backout 93`. Then, you can merge your new commit into the `stable` branch, and it will be *as though* you never committed 93. 93 will be in your history, but its code changes are gone.